# IronMq : mail doesn't send but the queue is working

Tags: laravel, smtp, queue, sendmail, iron

I use IronMQ for to send my email since (laravel framework)
1. for signup email (it's oki with my SMTP and IronMQ)
2. Notification email (between users).

I'm a problem with the n°2 : iron receive the queue and It work but my SMTP don't receive the message for to send it.
I don't understand why because the config SMTP and IronMQ does not change between the two (Mail::queue)

PHP Code :

```
/****************************
  Notification email (buged)
*****************************/
    $emailTo = $product->user->email;
    $emailFrom = $emailSend;

    $data = Input::only('messageSend', 'name');
    $data['product'] = $product;

    Mail::queue('emails.products.iWant', $data, function($mail) use($emailTo, $emailFrom){
        $mail
          ->from($emailFrom)
          ->to($emailTo)
          ->subject("Je suis intéressé(e) par votre produit");
    });

/****************************
     Signup email (it's oki)
*****************************/

    $data = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'key' => $activation_code);
    Mail::queue($view, $data, function($mail) use($email, $subject) {
        $mail
          ->to($email)
          ->subject($subject);
    });
```

With Mail::queue it's no possible to keep the message_id or it's Success or failed ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this answer if can resolve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229140/laravel-4-iron-mq-queues-fired-but-the-mail-is-not-sent

I have had a similar situation

Comment: Thanks johnnyfittizio